# ADOMD: Drill down levels without retrieving all members of level

Tags: adomd.net

I have code like the following:

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Dimension dimension = cubeDef.Dimensions[dimensionName];
string hierarchyName = matches[1].Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Hierarchy hierarchy = dimension.Hierarchies[hierarchyName];
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Level adomdLevel = hierarchy.Levels[levelNumber];
MemberCollection levelMembers = adomdLevel.GetMembers();
```

Which is good to get all the members at a level.

However what I want is to narrow the members to just the ones at have a certain parent.

So that the members are the children from a chosen parent drilled down on.

There are overloads for GetMembers, but I was not able to work out how I could use them to filter in only the parent dimensions children.

Is there a way to do this?

The code I have gets the full level and then filters in code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.Member memberData in levelMembers) 
{
    if (memberData.Parent.UniqueName != parentMemberUniqueName) 
    { continue; } 
    // code using child of parent here 
}
```

This is proving slower as I drill down deeper.

Thanks,

Jasonlan